# uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library

Tags: android, build, ionic-framework

I don't understand this error message

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\__temp-mobile-prev\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:67:5 Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\__temp-mobile-prev\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.paypal.sdk\paypal-android-sdk\2.14.2\AndroidManifest.xml
        Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments" to force usage
```

Because line *67* of *AndroidManifest.xml* looks like:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Where does *15* come from?

I use *ionic* to build my app. But I don't think that this is the problem.

Comment: `minSdkVersion __
        targetSdkVersion __` and `compileSdkVersion __` in Build.gradle(Module: app)

Comment: Do you use external libraries?

Comment: @YoannHercouet I just use the ionic framework. I don't know if they use external libraries. Maybe the ionic plugins are external libraries. The error occurs because the paypal plugin expect a minimum sdk version of 16

Answer (score 32):

The problem for me was in [cordova-plugin-browsertab](https://github.com/google/cordova-plugin-browsertab).

You need to change line 1 of `my_project/plugins/cordova-plugin-browsertab/src/android/BrowserTab.gradle` to

```
def minSdkVersion = 19
```

Make sure you have the minimum SDK added to your `config.xml`

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

Then remove and add cordova-android by:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: It's the same place which cause error in my project. But define <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" /> in config.xml doesn't help. I have modify the line 1 of my_project/plugins/cordova-plugin-browsertab/src/android/BrowserTab.gradle to: def minSdkVersion = 19 and then reinstall android platform.

Answer (score 31):

In the code editor of your app,
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
Search for `minSDKVersion`
Replace with the desired version number

Comment: Works great! Do not replace in build folder.

Comment: Very simple and works pretty well. Thank you.

Comment: Simple and great

Answer (score 26):

Maybe I found the problem.

I don't want to overwride the build.gradle, because cordova create this file dynamically. But I searched why that `cdvMinSdkVersion` returns a wrong value. And the reason was this [barcodescanner-plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/blob/master/src/android/barcodescanner.gradle). The plugin gradle file has this line

```
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = 15
```

which overwrite my value from *AndroidManifest.xml*. After I have remove and add the plugin again it works.
But I don't know why? Maybe someone could explain the order of the different gradle scripts.

Comment: You sir, deserve a beer!!

Comment: Make it 3 beers. I can confirm this fix to work. I'm working on Cordova 6.2.0, and it did the trick!

Comment: And another beer ;) Thx

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are saying but I did a grep on that line of code and it was within a Mapbox plugin which I removed and then the build was successful .. Crazy stuff but another beer from here

Comment: As Peter said, I had added cordova-plugin-mapbox, it has a mobile-mapbox.gradle file with the cdvMinSdkVersion of 15.  Now I wonder, did you ever find a less hacky solution, than editing the files of the plugin yourself?  I'm not sure from which direction to approach the problem.. config.xml, mapbox, other configuration option?  Rather strangely, my build error was: `Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.xwalk.core" to force usage`which mentions xwalk (we also recently added crosswalk plugin) but the fix was mapbox.

Comment: A  BEER FACTORY: the same line was in cordova-plugin-bowsertab 
thanks.

Answer (score 11):

As of release 2.14.0, the minSdkVersion has been increased to 16. If you prefer to have your app on a lower minSdkVersion and want to leverage the latest SDK, please disable PayPal for versions below API 16, add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools` inside the manifest's xml declaration, and add the following snippet to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="INSERT_YOUR_DESIRED_minSdkVersion_HERE" tools:overrideLibrary="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

The easier way to do this is to:

-Go to Build.gradle(Module:app).

-Change minSDKVersion 15 to minSDKVersion 16.

-Sync your project.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some context to understand the things:

By default, when importing a library with a minSdkVersion value that's higher than the main manifest file, an error occurs and the library cannot be imported. To make the merger tool ignore this conflict and import the library while keeping your app's lower minSdkVersion value, add the overrideLibrary attribute to the  tag. The attribute value can be one or more library package names (comma-separated), indicating the libraries that can override the main manifest's minSdkVersion.

For example, if your app's main manifest applies overrideLibrary like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.app"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="2"
            tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>
```

Then the following manifest can be merged without an error regarding the <uses-sdk> tag, and the merged manifest keeps minSdkVersion="2" from the app manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.lib1">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Answer (score 5):

In case of Hybrid/Ionic app such issue could get fixed by changing minSdkVersion in config.xml is what I did.

Answer (score 5):

work like a charm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aspireone.myapplication"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="28" android:minSdkVersion="14"
            tools:overrideLibrary="com.allyants.draggabletreeview"/>
```

from this error message:

```
 <!-- Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [com.github.jakebonk:DraggableTreeView:1.0.1] C:\Users\ASPIREone\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\DraggableTreeView-1.0.1.aar\45f4095d2e68f3e9a1fbc4b73c7f9c33\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
            or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 15,
            or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.allyants.draggabletreeview" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures) -->
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem started for me after I added "[jitPak](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-android-programmatically)" library for viewing PDF, the root cause of the problem turn out to be line 13 in build.gradel (Module Level). Just change the version from 15 to 16, will resolve the issue.

```
android {       // line 7 of build.gradle (module App)
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.web_app"
        minSdkVersion 15    // change this to 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem.
Right click on app folder in android studio, select 'open module settings' | or just press F4. Go to Flavors Tab and change Min Sdk Version to the latest.
Problem Solved.

Answer (score 2):

Increase the minSdkVersion as your requirement, hope it will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I will prove to you that The easier way to do this is to apply these 3 steps following:

1) Go to `Build.gradle(Module:app)`.

2) Change `minSDKVersion 15` to `minSDKVersion 16`. or `17`

```
// 19(for projectfolder/platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml)
```

3) Sync your project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when working on an android application using Flutter:

##### Flutter Suggestion:

[image]

##### Solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use @Naga suggestion, and it's work. 
config.xml that I change is not in the root of project, but in
`platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml`

and `minSdkVersion` in AndroidManifests.xml are not overwritten again

Comment: When I generate app using cordova build android it automatically overrides the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.
Change `minSdkVersion 15` to `minSdkVersion 16` in build.gradle(module: app)

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that the minimal android version of the paypal library is 16, not your own app's version.

If one of the 3rd party libraries you use has the bigger minimum version than your version, you have to increase your minSdkVersion to them.

Answer (score 1):

Go to build.grade and inside the defaultConfig there is minSdkversion and change that to 17 and sync now and it work i mean it at least worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your version `'audioplayers: ^0.17.1'` to `'audioplayers: ^0.16.1'` in `pubspec.yaml` and pub get the dependencies of `'audioplayers: ^0.16.1'`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. And I solve it changing in C:\Users\"Username"\.gradle\gradle.properties cdvMinSdkVersion to 19

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
cdvMinSdkVersion=19
```

I found out when I Import the project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

**Set the minSdkVersion in android/app/build.gradle:**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem today when I added firestore dependency in flutter. It was solved by doing mentioned changes in the **android/app/build.gradle** file

**Before**

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSDKVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

**After**

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

N.B : doing minSDKVersion 19 won't work change it to minSDKVersion 21.

In case if above changes does not work you can follow steps mentioned in following website.
https://ao-system.net/en/note/224

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow these three steps to solve this error in ionic 3

1. In `projectfolder/platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml` change

   ```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
   ```

   to

   ```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
   ```
2. in `projectfolder/platforms/android/gradle.properties` change

   ```
   cdvMinSdkVersion=16 or X
   ```

   to

   ```
   cdvMinSdkVersion=19
   ```
3. in  `projectfolder/config.xml`
   change

   ```
   <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
   ```

   to

   ```
   <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it was to go to `platforms\android` folder and did a `find-in-folder` from my VS code editor for `minSdkVersion` and replaced all `minSdkVersion=16` to `minSdkVersion=19` regardless of whether cordova generated it dynamically or not. Everything worked fine for me after that.

Answer (score 0):

go to the folder **/platforms/android/android.json**
change the minsdk version to whatever you want

```
{
       "xml": "<preference name=\"android-minSdkVersion\" value=\"22\" />",
       "count": 1
},
```

then go to the plugin that may have messed you up **/plugins/{yourplugin}/plugin.xml**
change the preference value too to the number you want

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
```

then check your **/platforms/android/build.gradle** file and confirm the same value

```
project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="29.0.2" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=22 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 5.1
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=29 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=29 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think try to delete implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' in folder android/App/build.gradle. before doing the long steps above

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31290050)

The OP has nowhere mentioned that its `build.gralde` file has a dependency related to `firebase` .

Answer (score 0):

The error shown means that the package that you are using doesn't support minSdkVersion 15. so try to change in your "Project/android/app/build.gradle" the following :
minSdkVersion from 15 to 16 or higher

Answer (score 0):

change this code to -->>>>
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion  ->>>
minSdkVersion 19

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN6Yt.png)

Change the minSdk to 19 or whatever it's asking for in debug console.

Answer (score 0):

`cordova-plugin-facebook-connect` had an outdated `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />` in its `plugin.xml` file. Changing it to the value I could see in the logs (`21` in my case) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

add next line to project_folder\android\local.properties

```
 flutter.minSdkVersion=21
```

edit minSdkVersion in  project_folder\android\app\build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
      ...
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
```