# Ionic cordova compile for android giving error on minSdkVersion smaller than version declared

Tags: android, cordova, compiler-errors, ionic3

Please help,

I was trying to update my android platform version to 7.1.0 but lots of problems came out, so I decided to put back the version 6.3.0 but when I did I could not compile anymore, when I try to compile for Android that's the error I get:

```
:processArmv7DebugManifest
/Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:52:5-74 Error:

    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4] /Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.xwalk/xwalk_core_library/23.53.589.4/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.xwalk.core" to force usage


See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

:processArmv7DebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4] /Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.xwalk/xwalk_core_library/23.53.589.4/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.xwalk.core" to force usage


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.71 secs

Error: /Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:52:5-74 Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4] /Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.xwalk/xwalk_core_library/23.53.589.4/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.xwalk.core" to force usage

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4] /Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.xwalk/xwalk_core_library/23.53.589.4/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.xwalk.core" to force usage
```

I am not sure where can I find this: 
**minSdkVersion 15**

**Edit 1:**

```
> cordova plugin ls
com.googlemaps.ios 2.7.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-contacts 3.0.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.4.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.15 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.10.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.3.2 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-linkedin 1.2.1 "LinkedIn"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 2.3.6 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
cordova-plugin-nativeaudio 3.0.9 "Cordova Native Audio"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 2.0.5 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-streaming-media 2.1.3 "StreamingMedia"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.1 "SocialSharing"
cordova-sqlite-storage 0.7.14 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 6.0.8 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"
twitter-connect-plugin 0.6.0 "Twitter Connect"
```

**Edit 2:**

```
Error: /Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/res/xml/authenticator.xml:2:81-93: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/icon').

/Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/res/xml/authenticator.xml:2:147-159: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'smallIcon' with value '@mipmap/icon').

/Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/armv7/debug/xml/authenticator.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/icon').

/Users/francisco/ionic-projects/jungery2/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/armv7/debug/xml/authenticator.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'smallIcon' with value '@mipmap/icon').



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your crosswalk plugin version changed during this process.  If you can check what version you had before your upgrade/downgrade (in your config.xml), then you can explicitly install the version you used to have.  If you don't happen to have that under source control, it looks to me like the minSdkVersion of 16 was added to Crosswalk version 2.0.0.  If you're forced to guess about what version you used to have, try something like 1.8.0 (or earlier).

**UPDATE**
Based on the barcode scanner comments, I would try one of these two options:

1. Add a min SDK version in your config.xml that is >=16.  Looks like the barcode scanner plugin may not overwrite it if you have it set >=16.
   `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />`
2. Try updating the barcode scanner to 7.1+

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you can see on my "Edit 1" my Crosswalk is 2.4.0 but it always was that version, but where is that minSdkVersion 15 coming from? I have searched the entire project and found nothing.

Comment: Assuming it isn't in your config.xml, my guess would be one of the plugins you are pulling in.  When you did your search, did you include the `plugins` folder?

Comment: It seems that the problem is somewhere else, as you can see here: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7284 - must be something about barcodescanner, I had problem with this plugin before and have no idea what I did then.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too.  This may give you some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293082/uses-sdkminsdkversion-15-cannot-be-smaller-than-version-16-declared-in-library

Comment: I removed the crosswalk plugin and I was able to use "cordova compile" with success, then I added the plugin again and ran "cordova compile" again with success, then I ran "cordova clean" and tried to run "cordova compile" again, please se my **Edit 2** and see the result, if you have any idea about the error.

Comment: At this point, if I were you I would remove the android platform, delete the `plugins` folder, delete the `node_modules` folder, and start with a fresh build.  Make sure your plugins are at the version you want.  If not, uninstall/re-install them.  Then do an `npm install`, then an `ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0`, and an `ionic cordova build android`.