# How can i Build My Project Without Manifest Merger Error

Tags: android

Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0] C:\Users\OM.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-auth-19.3.0.aar\8ec2095a0209a5b3eda53b7dd05e2414\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.auth" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: Th error is self explanatory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293082/uses-sdkminsdkversion-15-cannot-be-smaller-than-version-16-declared-in-library)

Answer (score 0):

Change the minSdk to 16 in the manifest